# "bash: nc: command not found" error on ssh multi-hop

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04.

When I use no-root account for ssh multi-hops, it's OK.

But when I switch to root account (by `$sudo -i`), the ssh multi-hops doesn't work and it always gives error "`bash: nc: command not found`", and /bin/nc is surely there!

Very strange. Anybody has some hints?

The multi-hops ssh config is something like this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config

# Multi-Hop SSH
Host serverA 
    HostName serverA.abc.net

# Multi-Hop SSH
Host sha
    ProxyCommand ssh -q serverA nc sha.abc.net 22
```

Comment: try `which nc` while being a non-root user. Probably `nc` is installed in a location which is not in root's `$PATH`

Comment: If you ssh into serverA as root, and try to run `nc` interactively?

Comment: @user3159253, not path issue: 
$ which nc
/bin/nc
$ sudo -i

# which nc
/bin/nc

Comment: @GordonDavisson, same error:  # ssh -q serverA.abc.net nc sha.abc.net 22
bash: nc: command not found

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's difficult to tell precisely what your problem is from this distance, but it's possible it has something to do with your path being unset, or set in correctly, in your shell environment on "serverA".

My initial suggestion, which I suggest you do not use, is to specify `nc`'s location with its full path.  Thus:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q serverA /bin/nc sha.example.net 22
```

Just remember for the sake of portability that `nc` may not live in this location on all systems. For example, it's at `/usr/bin/nc` on FreeBSD and OSX.

I don't recall what version of OpenSSH is included with Ubuntu 14.04, but if it's recent enough (i.e. OpenSSH version 5.4 or later), you could replace the `nc` command with SSH's internal `-W` option, which instructs ssh to run in "netcat mode".  I would replace your `~/.ssh/config` entries with the following:

```
# gateway host
host serverA
    hostname serverA.example.net

host sha
    proxycommand ssh -xaqW%h:22 serverA
```

Note that I'm also including `-x` and `-a` to disable forwarding of X11 and agent authentication.

As for your query about doing this as root, **I would suggest that you DO NOT use ssh as root**.  Either on the server or the client.  Confirm that `PermitRootLogin no` is set in your sshd_config file (in /etc/ or /etc/ssh/), and only ever authenticate as unprivileged users.  On the client site, build your automation into unprivileged users who, if they need access to certain root accounts on the remote system, get that access using sudo.  It's never a bad idea to do things the Right Way.  :)

Comment: Thanks Ghoti ! '-W' option is perfect, then no need to use 'nc' anymore.  But I would like to keep the question un-answered because it's a really strange problem that same 'nc' has problem for root but works well for non-root user.

Comment: Does my suggestion that you specify the full path to `/bin/nc` help?  If so, then I would suggest looking in to the `$PATH` set for your root user.  If it does not help, then there may simply be not enough information here to diagnose the behaviour you're seeing. For me, nothing else comes to mind except the unhelpful "but you shouldn't be doing it that way anyway". :)

Comment: Tried to specify the full path to /bin/nc but same error info.  I agree that your usage of '-W' option is better than 'nc', so perhaps  better to just forget the 'nc' problem and close this question. Thanks Ghoti.